# Allow a single day range in the reputation graph

Tags: feature-request, reputation-graph

I exchanged comments with a user a few minutes ago regarding the reputation cap and he said he thought he was going to get the Mortarboard badge for his activities today, but he wasn't sure. I went to his profile to check, but the reputation tab only on a user profile only allows you to select a range of 2-90 days. If you try to set the range to a single day, the graph doesn't do anything - it still shows the old list of "reputation items" and it doesn't even give you an error to tell you what's wrong.

If you only want to see your reputation for the current day, you can simply set "today" as the lower bound, and some date in the future as the upper bound. If you want to check a date in the past, you're out of luck.

I think there should be an update to allow you to set a single date range like you can do on the Recent page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't *exactly* possible, but I think what you want is there now.  There are 2 *major* changes to that page since yesterday:

- There is no reputation graph
- The grouping of data is now by date, with a chronological breakdown for that day (most recent thing that affected rep on top)
- Related to the question: the latest day which had some reputation changes (today for active users) expands on page load...so just visiting the profile rep page (clicking reputation from the profile popup for example) will show you a breakdown of your latest day.

So you can just go down the list and click the day you want to get a breakdown for that day...this should be more info than available anywhere before while at the same time being quick to access.  If you have further ideas for improvement, please offer suggestions.

---

For those curious about why this wasn't possible long before...it wasn't intentional.  It was  (well, I consider it) a bug in flot's selection plugin that made a bad decision about what was a "sane" selection, preventing very small (under a week) selections on our graph.

Comment: So... the reputation graph is gone for good?

Comment: @YiJiang - correct, it was never accurate and had many other issues, decision was made to burn with fire.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to see reputation accurately for any day: go to https://stackoverflow.com/reputation.

Or you can use my [reputation tracker](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx) for today/yesterday.

Comment: `/reputation` only works for your own rep. In the question I said that I was looking at someone elses (though admittedly your tracker would have worked for my purpose today). Also, off-topic, `/reputation` isn't the most readable thing in the world. (Also, "omg Jon Skeet replied to me!")

Comment: @AgentConundrum: Yes, but the user you were exchanging comments with could have looked at it for himself :) (Of course, my rep tracker works for any user - and is somewhat easier to read, although less complete as it doesn't show you things like capped votes.)

Comment: Point taken. I didn't even think to refer him to `/reputation` since we were talking about the rep cap assumed he had been here a while (I was wrong, FWIW). I guess I was just being a bit nosy.

Comment: @AgentConundrum: Nothing wrong with that :)